# SVN merge logs after fixing repository structure

Tags: svn, branch, history

When project started, there where no trunk, branches and tags directories. The project was in main root. Now I fixed that and it's ok besides one thing: to see the logs before the merge in TortoiseSVN I have to select the merge revision, right-click and select "Get merge logs" to see the whole history.

Does anyone know a method to import history into branch to see it all?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you are looking for the "Include merged revisions" checkbox in the lower left corner of the TortoiseSVN [Revision Log Dialog](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-showlog.html).

Comment: Yes, exactly that. Well, the next day, it works. Yesterday it wasn't working and I had to view the logs manually. Looks like the reboot helped with cache or something like that. Anyway thanks.